# Why my scrollbar is out of the screen? how to fix it? Flexbox, overflow-y: scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: here]

why the bottom of bottom scroll bar is gone? I think its went too deep to the bottom.
and the "no image" box is not 100% appear? how to fix this?

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
    height: 45px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;  
}


.main-content {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gambar {
    margin: 15px auto;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="item">
                Im header
            </div>

            <div class="main-content">
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The case is, I want use flexbox, but the header is always appears so I need scroll system in the main content part only
And this scroll bar only appears in chrome, when I open it using edge or firefox, its gone, the scroll bar is gone, why?

Comment: if you run the code in edge or firefox it will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `main-content` element is set to 100% of the viewport height, but since the `item` header already takes up some of that height, you end up with an overflowing element that is pushed past the viewport height. You can resolve this by subtracting the item height as such:

```
height: calc(100vh - 45px)
```

Please check the snippet below:

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
    height: 45px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;  
}


.main-content {
    height: calc(100vh - 45px);
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gambar {
    margin: 15px auto;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="item">
                Im header
            </div>

            <div class="main-content">
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
                    <div class="gambar"> No Image </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```